# REGEX: Put a space every 3 digits without using " "

Tags: regex, formatting, number-formatting, space, digits

**Hello !**
I've been looking for more than a day now but I can't find an answer, so I'm coming here to ask my problem!

**Explanation:**
I created a game thanks to a Discord bot which allows to use many functions (Atlas), one of which is the one I will talk about: replace. What I'm trying to do is by using the REGEX, put a space every three digits to format the numbers like this:

**Base number:**

```
25
321
54500
78545515201
```

**After formatting:**

```
25
321
54 500
78 545 515 201
```

But in the replacement section, spaces " " are trimmed from the front and back, so I can't do `$1` . However, if I do `$1 $2`, the space between the two arguments is counted.
**So what I'm looking to do is format my numbers using the replacement as** `$1 $2` **so that the space is counted.**
If anyone has the solution, I will really thank you!

**EDIT:** here is the link about the replace function: https://atlas.bot/documentation/tags/replace

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: There is no particular language, it's a Discord bot that handles that.

Comment: Does Discord Bot use PCRE?

Comment: I don't know much about REGEX, so I couldn't really tell you about it. In the meantime, here is how it looks:
The ; are just used to separate functions. Everything is closed in a hug.
e.g: {replace;string;search;replace}

I have already used this function which allowed formatting numbers with virugles, but unfortunately I need to use spaces for my game.
The function in question: {replace;12345;(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$);$1,}

Comment: Oh okay, see my answer

Comment: Try `{replace;12345;\B\d{3}(?=(?:\d{3})*\b); $&}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of an empty capture group to assert a position without a char capture so that your replacement can be `$1 $2`:

```
(\d)()(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

Here it is in JS:

https://regex101.com/r/virtsL/1/

But it's also compatible in PHP (PCRE), Python, and Java.

Attribution: regex originally from https://coderwall.com/p/uccfpq/formatting-currency-via-regular-expression and I just added the empty capture group.

---

Per your comments, here is a working version of your attempt; slightly modified:

```
(\d)()(?=(\d\d\d)+(\D|$))
```

https://regex101.com/r/McrHgj/1/

Comment: It doesn't work, I think my Discord bot is not compatible with this language .. :(

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much, it works!
You are just amazing! :D

Comment: @Kydaix You're welcome. In the future you should always post what you've attempted and link to any official documentation you find especially for a niche product like yours.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputStr = `
25
321
54500
78545515201
`

const res = inputStr.replace(/(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))/g, " ")
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to do... I have to use "$1 $2".